# How to use push{lr} pop{pc} in ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I've been trying this for days and looking all over the net but haven't gotten a solution so I'll try to ask here: I have this simplified code as an example - it should blink a LED on a raspberry without an OS (Standalone). As of now the LED turns on and never turns off again. The delay loop isn't the problem, since it works when used in place of "bl delayloop", the problem lies in the push pop. Those need to be used in order for me to translate it into a more complex project, bx lr isn't an option. Any help is extremely appreciated!!

```
_run_morse:

_short_blink:
    
    str r1,[r0,#GPSET0]

    mov r10,#0

    bl delayloop
    
    str r1,[r0,#GPCLR0]
    
    mov r10,#0

    bl delayloop

b _run_morse

delayloop:

    push {lr}

    delayloop2:

    add r10,r10,#4

    cmp r10,r2

    bne delayloop2

    pop {pc}
```

Comment: What environment does code run in? Stand-alone? Linux? RISC OS?

Comment: What is `r2`? If it's not a multiple of 4, `delay_loop` will never return.

Comment: why isnt bx lr an option, it is fully supported here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you not have set the stack pointer (`sp`/`r13`) to pointer to suitable memory and the program does not run under an operating system that initialises it for you.

You should set `sp` to point to just above the area of memory you wish to use as a stack.

Comment: Thank you really really much!! This worked!

Answer (score 1):

To return from a leaf subroutine on armv7, one should simply `mov pc, lr` without the need to access the stack.

The *caller* OTOH, should `push lr; pop pc`, because it needs to return too and it needs to trash the register *lr*. One can anyway choose to use this paradigm throughout the code.

I would rather suspect that the number of clock cycles spent in the delayloop2 must either  be far too low for the LED to blink, the delayloop2 never returns, or the code to turn off the LED is failing.

Comment: armv7 or anything at or after armv4t should be bx lr not mov pc,lr

Comment: some pis are armv6 others armv7 compatibility mode in an armv8 and one was armv7 without the aarch64.  armv6 supports bx lr as well.

Comment: @DWelch: The OP specifically said don't use `bx lr`.  Code that doesn't use memory is quite flexible.  Where do you see that `mov pc,lr` is not permitted?  It is not recommended because it is slower.  `bx lr` allows interoperability and is faster.  But if `mov pc,lr` is not permitted, the newer ARMs would not be backwards compatible.  That would be surprising.  Run without the stack; try that in anything but assembler! `+1`